# Object is nil when initialized as instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, instance-variables

I'm new to Ruby, and to Rails. I'm failing to understand why the following happens. I'm using SendGrid to send emails. I've defined a class and a method:

```
class EmailService
  include SendGrid

  def send_email
    from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    to = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
    content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
    mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

    response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
  end

end
```

This works perfectly. However, I think it'd be better to initialize the client only once, and not every time the method is called. So I've extracted it as an instance variable.

```
class EmailService
  include SendGrid

  @send_grid = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])

  def send_email
    from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    to = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
    content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
    mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

    response = @send_grid.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
  end

end
```

Now I get `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'client' for nil:NilClass>`. By bebugging I see that `@send_grid` is nil.

I'm invoking the method with `EmailService.new.send_email`. To my understanding, `@send_grid` is an instance variable and should be initialized with the class.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Put that in a constructor. In your snippet that assignment expression is executed but in another scope that you don't have in the `send_email` method

```
class EmailService
  include SendGrid

  def initialize
    @send_grid = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
  end

  def send_email
    from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    to = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
    content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
    mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

    response = @send_grid.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
  end
end
```